# Mount ISO with a drive letter via Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to mount an ISO and I would like to associate a drive letter with that mount.   I would like to specify the drive letter as say Y:\
The below does not work, can anyone help me out.   Thanks

```
#Variable Declaration
$isoImg = "P:\Software\Windows10CurrentVersion\Windows10.iso"

#Mount ISO and Gather Drive Letter
Mount-DiskImage -ImagePath $isoImg -PassThru | Out-Null

#Obtain Drive Letter
$driveletter = (Get-DiskImage $isoImg | Get-Volume).DriveLetter
```

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/968495/how-can-an-iso-image-be-mounted-to-a-specified-drive-letter-in-powershell

Comment: Use `Mount-DiskImage` with `-NoDriveLetter` and then assign the mount to a drive-letter using `mounvol` ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mountvol )

Comment: Can you be more specific as I am learning PowerShell

Comment: Please read the ServerFault link I posted.

Answer (score 2):

You could mount the ISO and accept (for now) the automatically assigned drive letter. 
It is possible to change that afterwards, but you will need to run that as Administrator:

```
# the full path to the ISO file
$isoPath = "P:\Software\Windows10CurrentVersion\Windows10.iso"

# mount the ISO, but first check if it is already mounted
$isoDrive = Get-DiskImage -ImagePath $isoPath
if (!$isoDrive) {
    $isoDrive = Mount-DiskImage -ImagePath $isoPath -PassThru
}
# $isoDrive is a Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance#ROOT/Microsoft/Windows/Storage/MSFT_DiskImage

# get the DriveLetter currently assigned to the drive (a single [char])
$isoLetter = ($isoDrive | Get-Volume).DriveLetter
```

Rename the driveletter for this drive.
**This part needs to be run as Administrator**

```
# find the volume by its automatically assigned driveletter and set the new drive letter
$drive = Get-WmiObject Win32_Volume -Filter ('DriveLetter = "{0}:"' -f $isoLetter)
$drive.DriveLetter = 'Y:'
$null = $drive.Put()
```

To dismount the iso drive:

```
$isoDrive | Dismount-DiskImage | Out-Null
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

You can mount the ISO image and then assign the drive letter like this:

```
# ISO image - replace with path to ISO to be mounted
$isoImg = "P:\Software\Windows10CurrentVersion\Windows10.iso"

# Drive letter - use the required drive letter instead of Y:
$driveLetter = "Y:"

# Mount the ISO, without having a drive letter auto-assigned
$diskImg = Mount-DiskImage -ImagePath $isoImg -NoDriveLetter

# Get mounted ISO volume
$volInfo = $diskImg | Get-Disk | Get-Partition | Get-Volume

# Mount volume with specified drive letter (requires Administrator access)
mountvol $driveLetter $volInfo.UniqueId
```